Visual Studio 2022 - OLEDB SQL Anywhere 17
I have recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2019 to Visual Studio 2022. After installing SSIS  and creating a new solution I have noticed that there are several OLEDB Providers missing in VS2022 compared to VS2019.
How do I install the missing OLEDB providers or has something changed.
VS2022 OLEDB Providers

VS2019 OLEDB Providers

How do I add the missing providers?
Thanks

VS 2022 only support x64. I installed the x64 drivers

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
